# Dynamically retrieve JSON into datatable ORacle 12c version 1

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I need to convert JSON into data table (key value columns) in Oracle 12c v12.1.0.2

So for eg: there is a JSON string like `{"ID": 10, "Description": "TestJSON", "status":"New"}`

I need this converted to :

```
Column1          Column2
------------------------------------
ID                  10
Description         TestJSON
status              New
```

Now my JSON string could change the number of attributes and hence I require to keep the conversion dynamic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using the hierarchy query and `REGEXP` as follows:

```
SQL> with dataa(d) as
  2  (select '["ID": 10, "Description": "TestJSON", "status":"New"]' from dual)
  3  --
  4  -- Your query starts from here
  5  SELECT TRIM('"' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR,'[^:]+',1,1)) AS COL1,
  6         TRIM('"' FROM TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR,'[^:]+',1,2))) AS COL2
  7    FROM
  8  (SELECT t.d, trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(trim(']' from trim('[' from T.D)), '[^,]+', 1, COLUMN_VALUE)) as str
  9    FROM DATAA T
 10   CROSS JOIN TABLE ( CAST(MULTISET(
 11  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY
 12  LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(T.D, '[^,]+')) + 1
 13  ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST) ) LEVELS);

COL1            COL2
--------------- --------------------
ID              10
Description     TestJSON
status          New

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried the code and it worked. However, there are cases where the column value could contain commas for e.g. {"Description" : "TestJSON, Oracle,more string"}. The code splits this into multiple rows based on comma separation.